# Python recursion to find an item from folder or subfolder

Tags: python, recursion

```
Folder1
      |_Folder2
      |       |_vm1
      |       |_vm2
      |       |_vm3
      |_vm4
      |_vm5
      |_vm6
```

I have this structure now the method I am writing is:

```
def find_vm(folder, vm_name):
    for item in folder:
        if isinstance(item, my_folder_object):
            find_vm(item, vm_name)
        if item.name == vm_name:
            return item
```

Nested folders can be of any depth. This method is not working as expected.

What wrong am I doing here ?

Comment: is it an exercise to learn about recursion? have you tried to use `os.walk()` instead? e.g., `vm = next(os.path.join(path, d) for path, dirs, _ in os.walk(folder) for d in dirs if d == vm_name)`

Comment: you should use debugger or at least prints to localize the error.

Comment: Never heard about `os.walk` . Will definitely try to use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning anything in one of the branches:

```
...
    ...
        if isinstance(item, my_folder_object):
            val = find_vm(item, vm_name)
            if val is not None:
                return val
        ...
            ...
```

also, you need to decide what to do if a name is in more than one sub-folder;